# Ruby on Rails write Hash to file without : and => values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a hash in Ruby on Rails app, which needs to be written in file in below format -

```
{emp_id:15, emp_name:"Test", emp_sal:1800, emp_currency:"USD"}
```

But I am able to print it in file in below format -

```
{:emp_id=>15, :emp_name=>"Test", :emp_sal=>1800, :emp_currency=>"USD"}
```

Is there a way we can remove `:` of symbol and replace `=>` with `:` while writing hash to file?

Thanks!

Comment: Would you be okay with quotes around the keys? `{"emp_id":15, "emp_name":"Test"...}`? If so, that is a standard JSON file. Without the quotes, you'd have to do it manually (still not hard, but using standard formats is better).

Comment: Sorry but the requirements don't allow quotes around the keys.

Comment: Unfortunate. Are all keys primitive, or can they be hashes/arrays?

Comment: To me this sounds like a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you explain why you need the data in such a unique format in the file? IMO working with a more common and standardized data format like JSON or YAML would have many advantages. One very obvious advantage would be that you now need a special method to write the data into the file, but you would also need a special method to read and parse that data later on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in comments, you have to do this manually. Use `hash.map` to get key/value pairs and format them accordingly, join using commas, then add the curlies around the result. I use `#to_json` as a shortcut to add quotes to strings but not to integers.

```
hash = {emp_id:15, emp_name:"Test", emp_sal:1800, emp_currency:"USD"}

require 'json'
result = '{' + hash.map { |k, v| "#{k}:#{v.to_json}" }.join(', ') + '}'

puts result
# => {emp_id:15, emp_name:"Test", emp_sal:1800, emp_currency:"USD"}
```

Note that this only works on a single level. If you have nesting, a recursive function will be needed.

Comment: Cool. Is it possible to remove quotes for strings? For example: {emp_id:15, emp_name: Test, emp_sal:1800, emp_currency:USD}

Comment: Then just use `v` insted of `v.to_json`.